# Implement facebook integration in my app

Tags: android

The facebook login window show the error after entering the email id and password.:-
(invalid scopes:publish_stream.This message is only shown to developers.Users of your app will ignore these permission if present.Please read the documentation for valid permission at:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

snap for error :-[snap facebook integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1y7L.png)

how to solve these problem anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Did you set Up all Application Id and Hash Code in Facebook Application Dashboard

Comment: plz read this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please checkout my answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply Go in Settings in Application panel of facebook developer console and add your contact email in "**Contact Email**" Field.

Now go in App Preview section and make app **public**

[image]

Then click on **Submit items for Approval** and done all task.

[image]

Now go in app and test its worked successfully.

Comment: just check there will be green signal beside your app name?